# Can you identify this phyllanthus tree?

Tags: species-identification, trees

I have this tiny tree in my garden in Cancun, Q.Roo Mexico.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcAaU.jpg]
(More photos [available here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GcAaU.jpg).)

The little tree started to grow in a planter. I did not pay any attention to it until it grew to 10 cm. It does grow like any bigger tree, starting with one curving branch with regular leaves. I buy unsterilized soil from locals and always get something growing without planting. 
It is a *phyllanthus* plant, but that is all we know so far. 
By now I have 20 little ones and one big one, which is a year and a half old.

It certainly is not a *phyllanthus Niuri* which is an incredible medicinal plant, but with way less "tree attitude" than this one.

This lovely bonsai tree could be unknown to the world, hidden in the deep vegetation of the Yucatan peninsula, one of the world's regions with the highest tree variety.

**Can you identify this tree for me?**

Answer (score 3):

### *Phyllanthus caroliniensis*

> Phyllanthus caroliniensis, the Carolina leaf-flower, is a flowering plant native to the Americas, from the southeastern United States[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZF5BS.jpg) all the way to Argentina.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgMyK.jpg) The flowers are small and located where the leaf meets the stem.[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf0Lr.jpg)

[image: caroliniensis] [image: caroliniensis][image: caroliniensis]

> **Kingdom**: Plantae
>
> **Subkingdom**: Tracheobionta
>
> **Superdivision**: Spermatophyta
>
> **Division**: Magnoliophyta
>
> **Class**: Magnoliopsida – Dicotyledons
>
> **Subclass**: Rosidae
>
> **Order**: Euphorbiales
>
> **Family**: Euphorbiaceae – Spurge family
>
> **Genus**: Phyllanthus L. – leafflower

*Sources:*

- http://plants.usda.gov/core/profile?symbol=PHCA9
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phyllanthus_caroliniensis
- http://www.easttennesseewildflowers.com/gallery/index.php/Summer-Roadsides-White/Seedleaf50001
- http://sura.ots.ac.cr/florula4/find_sp3.php?key_species_code=LS001041&key_kingdom=&key_phylum=&key_class=&key_order=&key_family=&key_genus=&specie_name=caroliniensis

Comment: Hello Jordi Thanks or your reply. It's close in appearance, but the stems of the P carolinensis are thicker and green. And the leaves don't seem to be  translucent as the ones from my plant.   http://i.imgur.com/U7mU1DG.jpg

Answer (score 1):

the tree is identified.

http://chalk.richmond.edu/flora-kaxil-kiuic/p/phyllanthus_liebmannianus.html

Saludos
Bernhard